# Which prime divides $18^{29}+1$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, congruences

I am struggling with the following problem. Any help will be appreciated.

let $n= 18^{29}+1$. Prove that  $n$ is divisible by $19$. Prove that if $ p $ is a prime which divides $n$, $p\ne19$,then $p \equiv 1\pmod{58}$. Is $n$ is divisible by $59$?

Thank you.

Comment: **Hint.** For the first part, work modulo 19.

Comment: Actually I need the 2nd and 3rd part.

Comment: @swarnadip: If you already have been able to do some work on the exercise, you _really should_ reveal that work in the question, rather than just expecting random people on the internet to deliver full homework solutions without any input from you.

Answer (score 9):

$$18^{29}\equiv -1\pmod{p}$$
implies that the order of $18$ in $\mathbb{F}_p^*$ is $2\cdot 29=58$ (since $18\not\equiv -1\pmod{p}$), from which $58\mid |\mathbb{F}_p^*|$ follows, i.e.:
$$ 58\mid(p-1)\Longleftrightarrow p\equiv 1\pmod{58}.$$
For the second part, given that $p=59$, we have:
$$ 18^{29} \equiv 18^{\frac{p-1}{2}}=\left(\frac{18}{59}\right)=\left(\frac{2}{59}\right)=-1$$
since $59\equiv 3\pmod{8}$, hence $59$ is a prime divisor of $18^{29}+1$.

<sup>Here $\left(\frac{\cdot}{\cdot}\right)$ is the [Legendre symbol](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_symbol).</sup>

Comment: Jack - implies that the order of $18$ is an even factor of $58$ i.e. $2$ which leads to the solution $19$ from $18^2-1=17\times 19$ and $17$ does not solve the original equation, or $58$ and continue ...

Comment: @MarkBennet: yes, sure, but I was already assuming $p\neq 19$.

Comment: What I was worried about was that what you have written seems to exclude $19$ as a possible answer, and there is also a need to exclude other primes below $59$ - so show that $19$ is the only such.

Answer (score 4):

$18^{29}\equiv (-1)^{29}=-1\pmod{19}$, so $18^{29}+1\equiv 0$, so $19$ divides your number.

$18^{29}=18\cdot(18^2)^{14}\equiv 18\cdot 29^{14}=18\cdot (29^2)^7\equiv 18\cdot 15^7=(18\cdot 15)\cdot(15^2)^3\equiv 34(-11)^3\equiv 34\cdot 26\equiv -1\pmod{59}$, so $59$ divides your number.

Using a computer program, one can find that there are only 3 prime factors:
$$
18^{29}+1 = 19·59·2255781524824231358697279947382689
$$